# Why is the built-in distance function so much slower than my custom one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'd like to find the distance between 2 sets of coordinates.  First I use the built in function:

```
declare @lat1 real = 33.1, @lon1 real =-117.1, @lat1 real = 39.6, @lon1 real =-98.7
declare @source geography = geography::Point(@lat1, @long1, 4326);
declare @target geography = geography::Point(@lat2, @long2, 4326);

select  @source.STDistance(@target)
```

Now I use manual calculation to do the same thing:

```
 -- Kilometers to Miles: 0.621371, Earth Radius: 6378.137
 select 0.621371 * 6378.137 * ACOS(ROUND(
    (SIN(PI() *  @lat2 /180) * SIN(PI() * @lat1/180))
    + (COS(PI() *  @lat2 /180) * COS(PI() * @lat1/180) * COS(PI() * @lon1/180 - PI() * @lon2 /180)), 12))
```

In my testing on SQL Server 2014, the manual function is around 4x faster than the built-in one.  Is this normal or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: How are you measuring the time?

Comment: Also, where is this code? Are you executing it once manually in a console or is it inside a function called in a query involving many records? Or something else?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I am measuring it by encapsulating both sets of functionality in a function then calling it 1000 times against a table of lat/lon values.  Then I used `Include Client Statistics` in SSMS, ran the variants 10 times each, and looked at average `Wait time on server replies`

Comment: These code snippets don't run, and if I make what would appear to be the right fixes, I get wildly different results from the two calculations. This makes it hard to say what's going on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Server 2016 improved the perf](https://bobsql.com/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-native-spatial-implementations/) somewhat, but the basic reason is the STDistance is accurate, but simpler formulas can be faster, if you understand the errors they produce.

See eg [Geographic distance can be simple and fast](https://jonisalonen.com/2014/computing-distance-between-coordinates-can-be-simple-and-fast/), and a description of the algorithm used in STDistance:

> This paper outlines some geometric algorithms that are used in
> Microsoft SQL Server for processing geospatial data in a way that is
> independent of any cartographic projection.

[Geometric algorithms on an ellipsoid earth model](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1463434.1463487)

eg

```
declare @lat1 real = 33.1 
declare @lon1 real =-117.1
declare @lat2 real = 39.6
declare @lon2 real =-98.7

declare @source geography = geography::Point(@lat1, @lon1, 4326);
declare @target geography = geography::Point(@lat2, @lon2, 4326);

declare @distance float 
declare @i int = 0
declare @iter int = 1000 * 1000
declare @start datetime2 

set @start = sysdatetime()
set @i = 0
while @i < @iter
begin
  set @distance =  @source.STDistance(@target)   
  set @i += 1
end
select concat('STDistance: ',  datediff(ms,@start,sysdatetime()), 'ms' )


set @start = sysdatetime()
set @i = 0
while @i < @iter
begin
 set @distance =  0.621371 * 6378.137 * ACOS(ROUND(
    (SIN(PI() *  @lat2 /180) * SIN(PI() * @lat1/180))
    + (COS(PI() *  @lat2 /180) * COS(PI() * @lat1/180) * COS(PI() * @lon1/180 - PI() * @lon2 /180)), 12))  
  set @i += 1
end
select concat('calculation: ',  datediff(ms,@start,sysdatetime()), 'ms' )

set @start = sysdatetime()
set @i = 0
while @i < @iter
begin
  set @distance =  @source.STDistance(@target)   
  set @i += 1
end
select concat('STDistance: ',  datediff(ms,@start,sysdatetime()), 'ms' )

set @start = sysdatetime()
set @i = 0
while @i < @iter
begin
 set @distance =  0.621371 * 6378.137 * ACOS(ROUND(
    (SIN(PI() *  @lat2 /180) * SIN(PI() * @lat1/180))
    + (COS(PI() *  @lat2 /180) * COS(PI() * @lat1/180) * COS(PI() * @lon1/180 - PI() * @lon2 /180)), 12))  
  set @i += 1
end
select concat('calculation: ',  datediff(ms,@start,sysdatetime()), 'ms' )
```

outputs

```
--------------------------
STDistance: 2367ms


---------------------------
calculation: 1098ms


--------------------------
STDistance: 2347ms


---------------------------
calculation: 1105ms
```

Comment: Do you feel that my algorithm falls under the description of "simpler algorithms"?

Comment: I think that it isn't the calculation per se, but rather the involvement of the type (which of course has a higher overhead than simple scalar types). I modified the last loop and substituted for instance @@lat2 /180 to @@target.Lat /180, and now the time was higher than STDIstance (close to double the time).

Comment: @AngryHacker Yes.  Your formula is the Spherical Law of Cosines, and the Earth isn't a Sphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines